# Hiding Price Unless Logged In

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hidden, catalog

I have a membership site and need prices hidden until the user is logged in. How can I adjust this so prices are hidden only for users who are NOT logged in?

```
.imagemapper-wrapper .my_product_price { display:none !important; }
```

Currently prices are hidden from everyone.

Comment: There are two answers here, but I want to clarify: you want the prices hidden if the user *is* logged in?

Comment: I only want prices hidden if NOT logged in. It's a membership shop.

Comment: I adjusted the content of your question to be more clear. I would mark Jack Robson's answer as the accepted, since it relies on WC `logged-in` body class and is the simplest. My answer and mikerojas's answer also work, but are more heavy handed and unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

CSS only option:

```
    .imagemapper-wrapper .my_product_price {
      display: none;
    }

    .logged-in .imagemapper-wrapper .my_product_price {
      display: inherit;
    }
```

Comment: Even better since WP already adds the `.logged-in` class! Sometimes we overthink things. +1

Comment: Nice! This is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

One way you can do this is with the `wp_head` hook. In the hook you can echo the style if a user is logged in with `is_user_logged_in()`.  See below:

```
<?php

// functions.php

add_action('wp_head', function(){
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        echo '<style>.imagemapper-wrapper .my_product_price { display:none !important; }</style>';
    }
});
```

Another option is to use a custom css classname:

```
// functions.php
add_filter('body_class', function($classlist) {
    // add custom css class to body element if user is logged in
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $classlist[] = 'user-is-loggedin';
    }

    return $classlist;
});
```

Then is your css use the new classname:

```
// your-stylesheet.css
.imagemapper-wrapper .my_product_price { display:none; }
.user-is-loggedin .imagemapper-wrapper .my_product_price { display:block !important; }
```

Comment: Nice call on the body class as well!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use CSS instead of removing the pricing unless the user is logged in, use the `wp_head` filter. Put this in your `functions.php` file:

```
  add_action('wp_head', static function() {
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
         echo "<style>.imagemapper-wrapper .my_product_price { display:none !important;}</style>";
        }
   }
```

This uses `is_user_logged_in()` function to test if the user is logged in. If the user is not logged in, print this style in your header.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up merging two answers together. display: inherit wasn't working so I tried block !important instead and it worked like a charm. Thank you all for your advice and suggestions. I am now able to hide both the price and add to cart buttons when a user is NOT logged and show them when they are! I was beyond excited when I finally got this to work. Thank you all!

```
#mega_main_menu>.menu_holder>.menu_inner>ul>li.default_dropdown .mega_dropdown>li>.item_link {height:auto}

.logged-in .imagemapper-wrapper .my_product_price {
      display: block !important;
    }

.imagemapper-wrapper .my_product_price { display:none !important; }

.logged-in .imagemapper-wrapper .my_add_item { display:block !important; }

.imagemapper-wrapper .my_add_item { display:none !important; }

.logged-in .my_product_footer .my_view_item {width: 50%}

.my_product_footer .my_view_item {width: 100%}
```